# `Reduce` with an inequality that involves `ProductLog` is running forever

Tags: equation-solving, special-functions

I'm trying to make a comparison between two sides, one of which involves Lambert $W$ function. See my code:

```
Assuming[bmax ((-1 + lm) W - WB) > lm W bD && bmax > bL > bD && lm > 1 && bmax > 0 && w > 0 && W > 0 && WB > 0, FullSimplify@Reduce[bmax E^ProductLog[(bD W + bmax WB)/(bmax W - bmax lm W)] > bD]]
```

This code is running forever. Can anyone help please?

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
Do[
  lm=RandomReal[{1,10}];bD=RandomReal[{-10,10}];bL=RandomReal[{bD,10}];
  bmax=RandomReal[{bL,10}];W=RandomReal[{0,10}];WB=RandomReal[{0,10}];
  If[bmax((lm-1)W-WB)>lm W bD,
    If[Im[bmax E^ProductLog[(bD W+bmax WB)/(bmax W-bmax lm W)]]!=0,
      Print[{bmax E^ProductLog[(bD W+bmax WB)/(bmax W-bmax lm W)],">",bD,
        bmax((lm-1)W-WB)>lm W bD && bmax>bL>bD && lm>1 && bmax>0 && W>0 && WB>0,
        "bmax=",bmax,"lm=",lm,"W=",W,"WB=",WB,"bD=",bD,"bL=",bL}]
]],{16}]
```

which after some delay will print things like

```
{2.21858+4.86767 I,>,-1.67293,
 True,
 bmax=,9.00708,lm=,2.08953,W=,2.69263,WB=,2.68902,bD=,-1.67293,bL=,1.44401}
```

showing that for some values of your parameters which satisfy all your assertions that your expression is not greater than bD because your expression is complex. True shows that all the assertions were True. The list of parameter names and values shows the exact combination that results in this counterexample.

If it doesn't print anything then run it again because sometimes 16 iterations isn't enough to find a counterexample.

Check all this VERY carefully to make certain there are no mistakes.

Comment: Thanks! May I ask: How do you interpret the result? The result prints $>$ with `True`. Why does it mean the LHS is not greater than RHS (bD)?

Comment: Is there any way to do this analytically (without numbers) so that a general statement can be derived?

Comment: Then we cannot even say LHS $<=$ bD, right? There is no lower case w. (6 weeks!!!!)

Comment: But I should really be able to tell which is bigger between LHS and RHS; I wonder how I should proceed if this comparison cannot be made...

Comment: If you look at https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ProductLog.html and you click on the orange Details you see `For z>-1/e, ProductLog[z] is real.` Is there any chance that your assertions should somehow include that `z>-1/e`? Or is there any chance that there is any tiny flaw in your construction?

Comment: Yes, you are right, but unfortunately there is no necessity for z > -1/e in my case. And I'm sure there is no error in my construction. In any case, thanks so much for your help, Bill!

Comment: Since you "should really be able to tell which is bigger" and you can't when it is complex and you are certain there is no error then that seems to be a blinking sign that something very important to understand is going on in that particular case. I would go figure out what that something is and why. I would expect that understanding would be very enlightening.

Comment: That will be great, Bill! Yes, I also checked graphically that I should be able to tell which is bigger. That's why I also felt that it is a puzzle to have a complex number.